# HttpClientResponseException: Empty body

Tags: micronaut

I am getting confuse to using `declarative http client`.

I am trying to test to create a `declarative http client`. But I am getting this error.

```
15:34:16.455 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR i.m.r.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor - Type [micronaut.http.client.repository.ItunesClient$Intercepted] executed with error: Empty body
io.micronaut.http.client.exceptions.HttpClientResponseException: Empty body
        at io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient.lambda$retrieve$0(BlockingHttpClient.java:140)
        at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
        at io.micronaut.http.client.BlockingHttpClient.retrieve(BlockingHttpClient.java:140)
        at io.micronaut.http.client.interceptor.HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.intercept(HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.java:535)
        at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:40)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:146)
        at io.micronaut.retry.intercept.RecoveryInterceptor.intercept(RecoveryInterceptor.java:73)
        at io.micronaut.aop.MethodInterceptor.intercept(MethodInterceptor.java:40)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.proceed(InterceptorChain.java:146)
        at micronaut.http.client.repository.ItunesClient$Intercepted.search(Unknown Source)
        at micronaut.http.client.controller.MusicController.search(MusicController.java:37)
        at micronaut.http.client.controller.$MusicControllerDefinition$$exec1.invokeInternal(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethod.java:144)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$BeanExecutionHandle.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:2694)
        at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:295)
        at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:122)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.lambda$buildResultEmitter$17(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:1358)
```

this is my code.
https://github.com/akyong/micronaut-http-client/blob/master/src/main/java/micronaut/http/client/controller/MusicController.java#L25-L37

it works if i change `List<Album>` to `String` like this.

```
public String search(String searchTerm, @Nullable @QueryValue String maxResults) {
        log.info("searchTerm : {}",searchTerm);
        log.info("maxResults : {}",maxResults);
        final int limit;
        if(StringUtils.isDigits(maxResults)) {
            limit = Math.min(25, Integer.parseInt(maxResults));
        } else {
            limit = 25;
        }

        String result = itunesClient.search(searchTerm, limit);
        return result;
    }
```

ItunesClient

```
@Get("/search?limit={maxResults}&media=music&entity=album&term={term}")
    String search(String term, int maxResults);//From SearchResults to String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `src/main/resources/application.yml` set this...

```
micronaut:
  codec:
    json:
      additionalTypes:
        - text/javascript
```

This is needed because of the response content type coming back from Apple.  See https://github.com/jeffbrown/music-search/blob/30cda075cb8e9450ff920349ca5d5e986db32fbf/music-service/src/main/resources/application.yml#L13-L16 for an example.

Comment: It looks like you had set `micronaut.server.codec.json.additionalTypes` instead of `micronaut.codec.json.additionalTypes`.

Comment: thank you, i do not know that is needed. thank you very much

Comment: is this because of `Content-Type` from Apple is `text/javascript` ?

Comment: "is this because of Content-Type from Apple is text/javascript ?" - Yes

Comment: Is it possible set it by JacksonFeatures anotation for single endpoint of HTTP declarative client?